# How to use Scala code snippet within Java method? (example for Spark)

Tags: java, scala

I would like to call Scala code from Java. However I can only manipulate a specific portion of the code (the code within the apply method in the example below). Additionally I can add JARs to the class path.

## Example

### pure Java Code:

```
// system imports
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.*;
import com.knime.bigdata.spark.core.exception.*;
import com.knime.bigdata.spark1_6.api.RowBuilder;
import com.knime.bigdata.spark1_6.jobs.scripting.java.AbstractSparkJavaSnippet;
import com.knime.bigdata.spark1_6.jobs.scripting.java.AbstractSparkJavaSnippetSource;
import com.knime.bigdata.spark1_6.jobs.scripting.java.AbstractSparkJavaSnippetSink;

// Your custom imports:

// system variables
public class SparkJavaSnippet extends AbstractSparkJavaSnippet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


// Your custom variables:

// expression start
    public JavaRDD<Row> apply(final JavaSparkContext sc, final JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD1, final JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD2) throws Exception {

    //*************************************************
    //Specify the fraction of data to sample and if
    //the sampling should be performed with replacement
    //*************************************************
    final double fraction = 0.5;
    final boolean withReplacement = false;  
    //final boolean withReplacement = true;


    //Returns a sample of the incoming RDD
    return rowRDD1.sample(withReplacement, fraction);

// expression end
    }
}
```

### partly Scala code (not working):

```
// system imports
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.*;
import com.knime.bigdata.spark.core.exception.*;
import com.knime.bigdata.spark1_6.api.RowBuilder;
import com.knime.bigdata.spark1_6.jobs.scripting.java.AbstractSparkJavaSnippet;
import com.knime.bigdata.spark1_6.jobs.scripting.java.AbstractSparkJavaSnippetSource;
import com.knime.bigdata.spark1_6.jobs.scripting.java.AbstractSparkJavaSnippetSink;

// Your custom imports:

// system variables
public class SparkJavaSnippet extends AbstractSparkJavaSnippet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

// Your custom variables:

// expression start
    public JavaRDD<Row> apply(final JavaSparkContext sc, final JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD1, final JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD2) throws Exception {

    //Scala code begins here
    val fraction = 0.5
    val withReplacement = false
    rowRDD1.sample(withReplacement, fraction)
    //Scala code ends here

// expression end
    }
}
```

## Question

How do I write the code between `//Scala code starts here` and `//Scala code ends here` such that I can use Scala code in there - embedded in the Java code?

(**I cannot change the code outside those comments! However I can add JARs to the class path!**)

Comment: You can't just "mix-in" Scala into Java... What is stopping you from using the equivalent Java API?

Comment: You can't just write scala code there, you can only forward to a scala object. check this site out: http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~michelou/scala/using-scala-from-java.html

Comment: @cricket_007: Java sucks ;-).

Comment: Java is verbose, yes, but if you have the option, then just use the Scala API... Or use Java 8 and lambdas to take some of the bitterness away

Comment: @cricket_007: I do not have the option to use the Scala API, but Java 8 seems to be available - not sure though whether the Spark API allows for Java 8 lambdas. Thanks for the tip anyway.

Comment: Spark 2.0 dropped support for anything but Java 8, so it might be possible

Comment: @cricket_007: Do you mean with "anything" all the other Java versions or do you mean also Scala, R, Python? (The later I do not see from the documentation.)

Comment: You don't see it because that doesn't make sense :) Spark is written in Scala

Comment: @cricket_007: I meant: I do not see that Scala, R, Python are not supported (thus assuming they are still supported).